# Enabling of SSL on the official postgresql docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker, ssl

I have an issue with enabling of SSL support on postgres docker image. The following configuration is used in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  postgresserver:
    image: postgres:14.5
    container_name: postgresserver 
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
      PGPORT: 5432
      command: -c ssl=on -c ssl_cert_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt -c ssl_key_file=/var/lib/postgresql/server.key -c ssl_ca_file=/var/lib/postgresql/CA.pem -c clientcert=verify-ca
    volumes:
      - "./certs/myCA.pem:/var/lib/postgresql/CA.pem"
      - "./certs/postgresserver.internal.crt:/var/lib/postgresql/server.crt"
      - "./certs/postgresserver.internal.key:/var/lib/postgresql/server.key"
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - postgresserver.internal
  openssl:
    image: shamelesscookie/openssl:1.1.1
    container_name: openssl
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true
   
networks:
  default:
    name: dummy network
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.177.0.0/16
```

The files server.crt, server.key contain the server certificate and the private key signed by my own CA athorities whose certificate is in CA.pem

According to the official postgres/docker documentation

https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md

it should works (Section: Database Configuration,

> From the PostgreSQL docs we see that any option available in a .conf file can be set via -c.

see also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/app-postgres.html#id-1.9.5.14.6.3 for further details). I have tried to connect  using the pre-installed psql-client from Windows PowerShell on host as follows:

```
 & 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin\psql.exe' "sslmode=require host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test"
```

This call have produced the following output:

```
psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: server does not support SSL, but SSL was required
```

The call without "sslmode=require" switch works like a charm.

I have also tried to use openssl from openssl container as follows:

```
openssl s_client -starttls postgres -connect postgresserver:5432
```

This call has produced the following output:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 1 bytes and written 8 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

What might be wrong here?

Alternatively: Working configuration is higly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What does "resp." mean?  please use formatting to clearly delineate what commands you ran and what errors you got.

Comment: Your docker-compose file doesn't seem to be valid.  Was there more to it?

Comment: My docker-compose contain a lot of other services. For sake of claritiy I have provided only relevant part of it. I have no problems with all other services. I have also no problems with connections to the postgres instance which do not enforce SSL encryption..

Comment: OK, but you should have no problem redacting the other services while leaving the file usable.

Comment: Which part of the docs suggested this formulation?  Please provide a link.

Comment: @jjanes: I have added the requested information.

Comment: The page you link to doesn't mention ssl at all, and all the usages there of `-c` are for `docker run`, not `docker-compose`.  I don't know what "command:" does under "environment" in docker-compose, but my guess is 'nothing'.  There are other (unofficial) images offered specifically for ssl, maybe you could look into those.

Comment: @jjanes: command  forward the parameters in the same way as docker run ....

Comment: command *nested inside environment* doesn't do that.